# Coding interview question- at what index to append a 0 to an array of integers to maximise the value of the array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Coding interview question- you have a list of integers (positive and negative). The total value of the list is the sum of all indices multiplied by their corresponding values. For eg. given [1, -3, 5, -2], the value is 1x1+ -3x2 + 5x3 + -2x4 = 2.
Find the index at which you should input a zero, that will maximise the value of the list.

I'm quite new to coding, and I can only think of the brute force solution of computing the value for all possible indices where you can place the 0, but this is too slow. What's a better way to solve this problem? (pseudocode, python or c++ is what I know)

Comment: So, do the brute force implementation, and then look at it and try to find ways to make it better.

Comment: @Marta Can you clarify one moment: when we input 0 in array - it revrite previous value on this position, or 0 inserts in array and moves all other values to the right? Which array we will get, if inserts 0 at first position at [1, -3, 5, -2] array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> computing the value for all possible indices where you can place the 0, but this is too slow

The key is that you should not have to compute the total value *from scratch* each time you put the 0 somewhere else. You would only need to check what the *difference* is that placing the 0 makes.

### Assuming *replacement* of a value with 0

The above mentioned difference really then is the negative value of the original term. If you maximise the difference it makes, you maximise the total sum.

For the given example, you would do this:

- Place 0 at the first position: difference = -1x1 = -1
- Place 0 at the second position: difference = 3x2 = 6
- Place 0 at the third position: difference = -5x3 = -15
- Place 0 at the final position: difference = 2x4 = 8

The maximum difference is achieved by placing the 0 in the last position, as that *increases* the total with 8, which is the greatest increase among the other options.

If you don't *negate* the products (like above), then it comes down to looking for the *minimum* term.

Here is a possible implementation in Python:

```py
data = [1, -3, 5, -1]

least = data[0]
best_pos = 1
for i, value in enumerate(data):
    product = value * (i + 1) 
    if product < least:
        least = product
        best_pos = i + 1

print("1-based postion: ", best_pos)  # 4
```

### Assuming *insertion* of a zero making list longer

If the zero is to be inserted, making the list longer, then compute the *accumulated* difference of *moving* values to the right, starting from the end of the list. As each value is shifted to the next position (to make room for the zero), its coefficient increments, and so the total increases with the value of that list element. Then keep track of where the accumulated difference is maximized:

```
data = [1, -3, 5, -1]

most = 0
total = 0
best_pos = len(data) + 1
for i in range(len(data) - 1, -1, -1):
    # assume insertion of 0 at index i
    total += data[i]  # shifting it will increment coefficient
    if total > most:
        best_pos = i + 1
        most = total

print("1-based postion: ", best_pos)  # 3
```

So for the example, the 0 should be *inserted* at position 3, i.e.

```
[1, -3, 0, 5, -1]
```

We can see how this maximises the effect of the 5, yet minimises the (negative) effect of the -3 (which stays put).

## Efficiency

Both solutions have a O(n) time complexity, as the list is scanned once, and each iteration takes O(1) time to complete.

Comment: Hmm, yes I thought about that. But I'm still not sure how to count the difference as I can only think about how all the numbers right of the 0 will change, after shifting it to the right (all indexes will increase by 1). What am I missing?

Comment: Added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Great solution. Another variation of this problem could be that instead of replacing the value at an index in the array by zero, assume you add instead, i.e. shift elements at index i one step to the right so that 0 resides at index i, old arr[i] resides at i+1 and so on.

Comment: This answer appears to assume that "inputting a zero at position i" means replacing the element i with a 0, rather than inserting a new 0 and shifting elements. The question asked was ambiguous in that regard, but @Marta's comment hints that the 0 should be inserted as a new element rather than replacing an element. So why is this marked as the accepted answer?

Comment: @Stef, thank you for your comment. Indeed, there is an ambiguity in the question. I have extended my answer with a solution for the alternative interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

When you add 0 at i'th position you just add to total value all integers, which position is not lower, than i.

example:

```
value([1, -3, 0 , 5, -2]) - value([1, -3, 5, -2]) =
= (1 + (-3)*2 + 0*3 + 5*4 + (-2)*5) - (1 + (-3)*2 + 5*3 + (-2)*4) = 
= 5*1 + (-2)*1 = 3.
```

So, you can just summ all possible suffixes of array and find it's maximum.

For you example here is the array of suffixes summs if we place 0 at i'th position: [1, 0, 3,-2 ,0]. Array maximum is 3 - so we should insert 0 between "-3" and "5".

Comment: Oh alright, yes that makes sense. That still means that I have to sweep through all possible places, and see how the sum of the integers to the left of the 0 changes, right?

Comment: Almost rigth. You should see at sum of the integers to the **right** of the 0 position (if 0 at position i - you have to sum values with index i , i+1, i+2 ... ). And you should check all positions, but add one int is more easy, than calculate whole value(array).

Answer (score 0):

Transforming Nikxp's answer into python code:

```py
import itertools

def find_pos(l):
  decreasing_cumsums = list(itertools.accumulate(l[::-1]))[::-1] + [0]
  return max(range(len(l)+1), key=lambda i: decreasing_cumsums[i])

print(find_pos([1, -3, 5, -1]))
# 2
print(find_pos([-1, -3, -5, -1]))
# 4
```

**How this works**

We store the decreasing cumulative sums using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```py
l                  = [1, -3, 5, -1]
decreasing_cumsums = list(itertools.accumulate(l[::-1]))[::-1] + [0]
decreasing_cumsums = [1-3+5-1, -3+5-1, 5-1, -1, 0]
decreasing_cumsums = [2, 1, 4, -1, 0]
```

When inserting the 0 at position `i`, we effectively shift all the indices of elements to the right of 0 by +1, so the value is increased by `+1*decreasing_cumsums[i]`.

Then we use python's builtin function `max`, comparing the indices with the custom key that is the decreasing cumulative sums.